# Avoiding callback hell. Meteor.call promise

Tags: javascript, meteor, promise

I've been trying to avoid callback hell in Meteor but first, I'll explain my problem:

I have some Meteor methods declared in server, and I invoke them using Meteor.call in client, but the main problem is I have tons of callbacks making debugging a really difficult task to make (and manteinance too...). This wouldn't be an issue if I work with a "small" project, but I'm building a big one and I was planning on using promises but for my surprise... it's not working since Meteor.call only accepts callbacks.

I've read a lot of posts here and in Meteor forums and none of them can help me... is there any solution to this? (I tried deanius:promise package and it's still the same...)

Edit: using Meteor 1.4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nowadays the ES7 Async/Await is there to help the "callback trouble". See explained very well here: http://rossboucher.com/await/#/10

```
async function () {
    let result1 = await Do.Something(1);
    let result2 = await Do.Something(2);
}
```

Comment: Should I install any package to use this? I'm having an unexpected token when i use `await`, otherwise, I got `undefined`

Comment: Finally I found the solution thanks to this, simply I had to make my function async to be able to use await...I created a intermediate function that returns a Promise and inside the promise funcion, make the Meteor.call

Comment: @Droontar Extended my example using async to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `bluebird` module for this. `promisifyAll` lets you convert all functions on an object to use promises instead of callbacks, so instead of using `Meteor.call` with a callback, you can use `Meteor.callAsync` as a promise.

With callbacks:

```
Meteor.call(..., function(...) {
    // ...
});
```

With promises:

```
Meteor.callAsync(...).then(function(...) {
    // ...
});
```

http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisifyall.html

Comment: So...using `bluebird` requires to modify the definition of those methods? or just simply `promisifyAll` where I call the methods? I mean, right now my methods are `return value;`, only using `promisifyAll` works? or I need to change it like `return new Promise...`?

Comment: You call `promisifyAll` on the `Meteor` object. For every method on the `Meteor` object that uses callbacks, `promisifyAll` automatically creates a new one that uses promises. You can call the new promisified methods normally. I added an example.

Comment: I can't use Meteor.callAsync, it's not a method (console). What package should I use? I'm using npm one, `bluebird`.

Comment: @Droontar `Meteor.callAsync` is created when you run `require("bluebird").promisifyAll(Meteor)`. After that you should be able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Libraries like AsyncJS https://github.com/caolan/async are a general answer to the "callback pyramid of doom" problem.

Basically the replace calls like

```
Do.Something(1, function(result) {
    Do.SomethingElse(2, function(result) {
       Do.YetSomethingElse(3, function(result) {
           .... 
       })
    })
})
```

With

```
asyncjs.series([
    function F1(callback) {
       Do.Something(1, callback);  
    },
    function F1(callback) {
       Do.SomethingElse(2, callback);  
    },
    ..... etc
])
```